# Simple Java program 100 times slower after plugging in USB hotspot

Tags: java, windows, performance, networking, windows-7

I have following Java program:

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        java.io.File.createTempFile("java_test", ".txt").delete();
        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - start ) / 1e9);
    }
}
```

Normally, it takes bout 63 miliseconds to execute:

```
$ java Main
0.06308555
```

But, once I connect Android phone as USB hotspot, it takes significantly longer. Depending on the machine anywhere from 3 to 40 seconds:

```
$ java Main
4.263285528
```

The strange thing is that nothing here is actually transferred over the network - plugged network adapters shouldn't matter.

I did a backtrace and it looks like majority of time is spent in `NetworkInterface.getAll` method:

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000023ae000 nid=0x142c runnable [0x000000000268d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.NetworkInterface.getAll(Native Method)
        at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.addNetworkAdapterInfo(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.getSystemEntropy(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x000000076afa2820> (a sun.security.provider.SecureRandom)
        at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x000000076af6bdc8> (a java.security.SecureRandom)
        at java.security.SecureRandom.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Random.nextLong(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.File$TempDirectory.generateFile(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
        at Main.main(Main.java:4)
```

which, in turn, seems to spend most of the time in `GetIfTable` Windows API method:

```
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`0257ed78 000007fe`fd7210ba ntdll!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0xa
00000000`0257ed80 000007fe`fd721252 nsi+0x10ba
00000000`0257ee20 000007fe`fd7211f9 nsi!NsiEnumerateObjectsAllParametersEx+0x2e
00000000`0257ee60 000007fe`fd7217b0 nsi!NsiEnumerateObjectsAllParameters+0xc9
00000000`0257ef00 000007fe`f9c7928d nsi!NsiAllocateAndGetTable+0x184
00000000`0257efd0 00000000`6f8c5a01 IPHLPAPI!GetIfTable+0xa9
00000000`0257f090 00000000`6f8c6980 net!Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_getMTU0+0x1a1
00000000`0257f150 00000000`6f8c6e57 net!Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_isP2P0_XP+0x88
00000000`0257f270 00000000`6f8c6058 net!Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_getAll_XP+0x23
00000000`0257f2a0 00000000`02867f54 net!Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_getAll+0x2c
```

`GetIfTable` seems to be the problematic function. I'm observing the same slowdown both in example program from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365943(v=vs.85).aspx and with following snippet:

```c
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    DWORD dwSize = sizeof(MIB_IFTABLE);
    MIB_IFTABLE *pIfTable = malloc(dwSize);
    GetIfTable(pIfTable, &dwSize, FALSE);
    pIfTable = malloc(dwSize);
    GetIfTable(pIfTable, &dwSize, FALSE);
    return 0;
}
```

How do I fix or workaround this problem?
I can create temporary files on my own and avoid calling NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces but SecureRandom is used all over Java standard library.
Is there a way to force SecureRandom not to use GetIfTable?

Java version:

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

Windows version:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
```

Problematic network adapter:

```
Name    [00000020] Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device
Adapter Type    Ethernet 802.3
Product Type    Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device
Installed   Yes
PNP Device ID   USB\VID_0FCE&PID_71C4&MI_00\7&6BE3F3B&0&0000
Last Reset  8/14/2016 12:26 PM
Index   20
Service Name    usb_rndisx
IP Address  192.168.42.183, fe80::90ab:3786:4396:2870
IP Subnet   255.255.255.0, 64
Default IP Gateway  192.168.42.129
DHCP Enabled    Yes
DHCP Server 192.168.42.129
DHCP Lease Expires  8/14/2016 3:27 PM
DHCP Lease Obtained 8/14/2016 2:27 PM
MAC Address 02:18:61:77:7D:72
Driver  c:\windows\system32\drivers\usb8023x.sys (6.1.7600.16385, 19.50 KB (19,968 bytes), 7/14/2009 2:09 AM)
```

Comment: Maybe it is not a Java-problem. If i connect my smartphone as USB hotspot, almost everythink is slower. It usually lasts about 5 minutes to open, for example, network settings on windows.

Comment: As a side note: this slow initialization happens _once_ in JVM lifetime, when some code use `java.util.Random` the first time. Therefore, subsequent calls to `java.io.File.createTempFile` should not be so slow. So maybe it is not such big problem for you, depending on your use case.

Comment: As another side note: it's amazing how deeply you investigated this problem before asking here. I learnt from your question. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to recreate the situation with your Java app and USB tethering with my Samsung Galaxy S7, but the problem does not occur here. The program performance stays exactly the same. My drivers for NDIS USB adapter are usb80236.sys and rndismp6.sys, version 10.0.10586.0, vendor Microsoft. Windows 10 64-bit. What is your configuration? Maybe it is a driver issue.

Comment: @kriegaex I have only tested this on Windows 7: `usb8023x.sys 6.1.7600.16385`. I will try 10 but I'm not sure I will be able to upgrade.

Comment: Also happened to me using Windows 10 64-bit: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10280

Comment: Seems related to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7039343

Comment: Also causes https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178894

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Default implementation of `SecureRandom` [scans network interfaces](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/d769ed8938d0/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/SeedGenerator.java#l182) as an additional source of system entropy. In order to avoid this, you need to register a custom [`java.security.Provider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Provider.html) that contains a different implementation of [`SecureRandomSpi`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandomSpi.html).

Fortunately, JDK for Windows already has a suitable `SecureRandomSpi` implementation that relies on Microsoft Crypto API: [`sun.security.mscapi.PRNG`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/d769ed8938d0/src/windows/classes/sun/security/mscapi/PRNG.java). Though this is non-public API, the class exists in all versions of OpenJDK and Oracle JDK from 1.6 to 9, and the fallback is available anyway.

There are two ways to register MS Crypto PRNG as the default SecureRandom algorithm.

**1.** From within the application by calling `WindowsSecureRandom.register()` at the very beginning.

```
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;

public class WindowsSecureRandom extends Provider {
    private static final String MSCAPI = "sun.security.mscapi.PRNG";

    private WindowsSecureRandom() {
        super("WindowsSecureRandom Provider", 1.0, null);
        putService(new Service(this, "SecureRandom", "Windows-PRNG", MSCAPI, null, null));
    }

    public static void register() {
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
            try {
                Class.forName(MSCAPI);
                Security.insertProviderAt(new WindowsSecureRandom(), 1);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // Fallback to default implementation
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2.** By reordering provider list in `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\java.security` file.

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI  <<<--- make it the first provider
security.provider.2=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.3=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.4=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.5=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
...
```

I've verified that with either solutions `SeedGenerator` and `NetworkInterface` classes are no longer loaded.

Comment: It looks like this would work. I'm a little worried about abusing non-API like that.

Comment: @Banthar I've found another cleaner solution that does not require patching system classes.

Comment: I think following answer provides cleaner and more portable programmatic solution without the explicit use of proprietary classes:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49322949/2725497

Comment: @patrikbeno Isn't your answer essentially about the same proprietary `sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI` provider?

Comment: @apangin, not directly. I have no explicit class reference in code, I lookup the provider named "SunMSCAPI", and move to position #1. I don't rely on sun.* packages.

Comment: @patrikbeno OK, let's pretend that **Sun**MSCAPI provider is not in sun package :) The idea was to replace only SecureRandom provider, not the whole security stack provided by SunMSCAPI. Otherwise you may just go forward with the option 2 above and not write any code at all.

Comment: Yes, this was my concern, too. (1) Replacing only SecureRandom provider is probably best option, but I definitely prefer to do this without compile or even reflective runtime dependency on sun.* packages. (2) Messing with JRE's java.security file affects all applications using same JRE installation, and I would definitely try hard to avoid that, unless there is very good reason to do so.

Comment: I've just tested the 2nd solution (cf java.security modification) and it works wrt not being stuck in SeedGenerator. But it breaks my system. I didn't get to the bottom of it but it looks like java.security.Key#getEncoded now returns null (tested with JDK 8 and 16)